# Split a time period into hourly intervals

Tags: java, android

How do I divide a time period (10:00:00PM - 20:30:00PM) into hourly intervals using java to get the following result?

```
10:00:00 - 11:00:00
11:00:00 - 12:00:00
12:00:00 - 13:00:00
13:00:00 - 14:00:00
15:00:00 - 16:00:00
16:00:00 - 17:00:00
17:00:00 - 18:00:00
19:00:00 - 20:00:00
20:00:00 - 20:30:00
```

Comment: This should help: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html

Comment: Your time intervals are probably missing some entries? Why, for instance, is there no 12:00-13:00 slot?

Comment: @MC Emperor my mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved part of my problem:

```
private ArrayList<String> setInterval(String start, String stop) throws ParseException {
    String strStart;
    String strEnd;
    ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault());
    Date dStart = df.parse(start);
    Date dStop = df.parse(stop);
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(dStart);
    cal.add(Calendar.HOUR, 1); //minus number would decrement the days
    while (cal.getTime().before(dStop)) {
        strStart = df.format(cal.getTime());
        cal.add(Calendar.HOUR, 1);
        strEnd = df.format(cal.getTime());
        arrayList.add(strStart + " - " + strEnd);
    }
    return arrayList;
}
```

Comment: FYI, the terribly flawed date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html) classes built into Java 8 and later.

Comment: Your code will be affected by anomalies, such as Daylight Saving Time (DST), in the wall-clock time of various time zones. If you want only time-of-day without date and without time zone, you should be using `LocalTime`.

Answer (score 1):

Make a `LocalTime` of the start and stop.

Add an hour to the start.

```
LocalTime lt = start.plusHours( 1 ) ;
```

Notice the immutable objects. Rather than alter the original object, we get a fresh new `LocalTime` object.

Compare to the stop by calling the `isBefore`, `isAfter`, and `isEqual` methods. If not yet past the stop, add another hour. If going past the stop, then use the stop itself rather than the next hour.

Collect into a `List < LocalTime>`.

If you want to track each entry as pair of `LocalTime` objects, define a class named something like `TimeSlot` with a pair of `LocalTime` member fields. The new *Records* feature previewed in Java 14 would do nicely here.

All this has been covered many times already on Stack Overflow. Search to learn more.

## Example app

Here is a working example app. This uses the new `Records` feature defined in [*JEP 359: Records (Preview)*](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/359), previewed in Java 14, working in [IntelliJ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliJ_IDEA) 2020.1 IDE.

```
package work.basil.example;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.LocalTime;

public record LocalTimeRange(LocalTime start , LocalTime stop)
{
}
```

We can fancy that up a bit.

We override `toString` to produce text in one of the four standard ISO 8601 format: HH:MM/HH:MM. We define an enum for the four types of formats specified by [ISO 8601 for time intervals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_intervals). Our `format` method takes one of those flags to produce text in one of the four standard formats.

We produce a [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Duration.html) object if asked. This class represents a span-of-time not attached to the timeline on a scale of hours-minutes-seconds.

Because this is a `record`, we need not override `equals` & `hashCode`. Nor do we need getter methods for the parts of start and end `LocalTime` objects.

```
package work.basil.example;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.LocalTime;

public record LocalTimeRange(LocalTime start , LocalTime end)
{
    public enum Format
    { START_AND_END, START_AND_DURATION, DURATION_AND_END, DURATION_ONLY }  // Per ISO 8601 standard.

    @Override
    public String toString ( ) { return this.format( Format.START_AND_END ); } // Per ISO 8601 standard.

    public Duration toDuration ( ) { return Duration.between( this.start , this.end ); }

    public String format ( LocalTimeRange.Format format )
    {
        return switch ( format )
                {
                    case START_AND_END -> this.start + "/" + this.end;
                    case START_AND_DURATION -> this.start.toString() + "/" + this.toDuration().toString();
                    case DURATION_AND_END -> this.toDuration().toString() + "/" + this.end.toString();
                    case DURATION_ONLY -> this.toDuration().toString();
                };
    }
}
```

We need a method to create the hourly time ranges.

```
private List < LocalTimeRange > hourlyRanges ( final LocalTime start , final LocalTime stop )
{
    // Verify arguments
    Objects.requireNonNull( start , "Received null time-of-day for start. Message # 51521a5c-5f49-4c74-98e3-fce2587edf77." );
    Objects.requireNonNull( stop , "Received null time-of-day for stop. Message # 41b98429-4edb-4209-a12f-e266dcae4a90." );

    // Logic
    int initialCapacity = java.lang.Math.toIntExact( Duration.between( start , stop ).toHours() + 1 ); // Returns the value of the long argument; throwing an exception if the value overflows an int.
    ArrayList < LocalTimeRange > ranges = new ArrayList <>( initialCapacity );
    LocalTime localTime = start;
    while ( ! localTime.isAfter( stop ) )
    {
        LocalTimeRange range = null;
        LocalTime hourLater = localTime.plusHours( 1 );
        if ( ! hourLater.isAfter( stop ) )
        {
            range = new LocalTimeRange( localTime , hourLater );
        } else
        {
            range = new LocalTimeRange( localTime , stop );
        }
        Objects.requireNonNull( range );
        ranges.add( range );
        // Prepare for next loop.
        localTime = hourLater;
    }
    ranges.trimToSize();
    return Objects.requireNonNull( ranges );
}
```

And some code to exercise it.

```
LocalTime start = LocalTime.parse( "10:00:00" );
LocalTime end = LocalTime.parse( "20:30:00" );
List < LocalTimeRange > ranges = this.hourlyRanges( start , end );

System.out.println( "ranges = " + ranges );
System.out.println( ranges.stream().map( range -> range.toDuration() ).collect( Collectors.toList() ) );
System.out.println( ranges.stream().map( range -> range.format( LocalTimeRange.Format.START_AND_END ) ).collect( Collectors.toList() ) );
System.out.println( ranges.stream().map( range -> range.format( LocalTimeRange.Format.START_AND_DURATION ) ).collect( Collectors.toList() ) );
System.out.println( ranges.stream().map( range -> range.format( LocalTimeRange.Format.DURATION_AND_END ) ).collect( Collectors.toList() ) );
System.out.println( ranges.stream().map( range -> range.format( LocalTimeRange.Format.DURATION_ONLY ) ).collect( Collectors.toList() ) );
```

When run:

> ranges = [10:00/11:00, 11:00/12:00, 12:00/13:00, 13:00/14:00, 14:00/15:00, 15:00/16:00, 16:00/17:00, 17:00/18:00, 18:00/19:00, 19:00/20:00, 20:00/20:30]
>
> [PT1H, PT1H, PT1H, PT1H, PT1H, PT1H, PT1H, PT1H, PT1H, PT1H, PT30M]
>
> [10:00/11:00, 11:00/12:00, 12:00/13:00, 13:00/14:00, 14:00/15:00, 15:00/16:00, 16:00/17:00, 17:00/18:00, 18:00/19:00, 19:00/20:00, 20:00/20:30]
>
> [10:00/PT1H, 11:00/PT1H, 12:00/PT1H, 13:00/PT1H, 14:00/PT1H, 15:00/PT1H, 16:00/PT1H, 17:00/PT1H, 18:00/PT1H, 19:00/PT1H, 20:00/PT30M]
>
> [PT1H/11:00, PT1H/12:00, PT1H/13:00, PT1H/14:00, PT1H/15:00, PT1H/16:00, PT1H/17:00, PT1H/18:00, PT1H/19:00, PT1H/20:00, PT30M/20:30]
>
> [PT1H, PT1H, PT1H, PT1H, PT1H, PT1H, PT1H, PT1H, PT1H, PT1H, PT30M]

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes. Hibernate 5 & JPA 2.2 support *java.time*.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

[image: Table of which java.time library to use with which version of Java or Android]

Comment: Some LocalTime methods like plusHours requires API level 26 in Android. My current min is 21. Unfortunately I can't upgrade for now.

Comment: @afazolo [*ThreeTenABP*](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP). The legacy date-time classes are truly terrible, and should be avoided.

Comment: @afazolo See links added in new section at bottom of my Answer.